# sppsvc(software protection) service keeps on stopping even if we try to start it

Tags: windows

**sppsvc**(software protection)service keeps on stopping even if we try to start it. I have tried to restart it also. I tried to start it from cmd promt also but after 30 secs to 1 min it goes to stop state. I tried to change the startup type also but it's grayedout. and present state is Automatic(Delayed start). Windows version is server 2012 R2.Can someone help me on solving this issue. Client requirement is to be in start state always

Comment: Why do you want to start it? This service starts and stops automatically as required.

Comment: Our client requires the service to be in start start always

Comment: Yeah that’s just not how the service works. Instead of trying to achieve the impossible, you must explain this to your client. What’s your client’s reasoning anyway?

Comment: Try editing the registry value at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform**  set **InactivityShutdownDelay** to 15180 (86400). That should keep it running for 24 hours.